# How to make this symbol (topology)?

Tags: symbols

Is it possible to produce this symbol?

[image]

I tried Detexify, but nothing.

Thanks

Comment: What is the symbol called or what does it represent? In a pinch, perhaps `\reflectbox{\rotatebox{180}{\pounds}}`.

Comment: Represents a topology. I always call it ''T''. Your answer is close...

Comment: Is it a stylized, "script" letter "T"?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a `$\mathscr{Z}$` from the `mathrsfs` package?

Comment: can you cite an example in context, preferably in a printed source?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Maybe I didn't write my question well. What I wanted to say was that this symbol comes from handwriting. Is not a symbol of latex, I think (that's my question: if is possible to create it?)

Comment: Could you trim your image a bit, and then just include it as a graphic?

Comment: First check https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/   If you are desperate enough, you could use tikz to draw it.

Comment: For topologies I understand that the greek letter tau (τ) is used, maybe this is a stylistic variant of that? In that case you could start with `\uptau` and add the line in the middle (it doesn't have the curly top though).

Comment: This is most probably a fancy script T, with a middle stroke possibly not to mistake it for other handwritten symbols. I see no reason for trying and reproduce it in print.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The website http://detexify.kirelabs.org/ unfortunately does not recognize many alphabets but it is a great tool altogether, otherwise.

I have worked on a certain university, once. It was common for lecturers to represent bases, σ-algebras, topologies, and alike in their published scripts with the `\mathcal`-alphabet. However, on a blackboard they wrote these letters with German *Kurrentschrift*. Similarly, they wrote Lie algebras and ring ideals on a blackboard with Kurrentschrift which is more or less a script version of Fraktur (another used option was to simply underline the letter on blackboard). This annoyed some students because they were not used to this script. Observe that *Sütterlin* is a simplified Kurrentschrift. **The OP's letter of question looks like a Kurrent E** (capital e) in some individual handwriting, compare these images:

- http://www.zinken.net/Fonts/Kurrent_700x400.jpg,
- http://www.museum-mittweida.de/s/cc_images/teaserbox_31174455.jpg?t=1413268322, and
- http://kryptografie.de/kryptografie/chiffre/images/altdeutsche-kurrentschrift.png.

Therefore you might check whether the "standard mathematical fonts" or Kurrentschrift is appropriate for a typeset project. If you want to use these scripts in a `TeX`-derivative you may have a look on

- https://ctan.org/pkg/sueterlin,
- https://ctan.org/pkg/schwell,
- https://ctan.org/pkg/fundus-sueterlin, and
- https://ctan.org/pkg/schulschriften.

These typefaces may not blend well with your main typeface. You might find other Kurrent typefaces and might be able to include them with `XeTeX` or `LuaTeX`. To conclude this we may have a look on some examples. Note that I needed to change some suggested solutions because they would result in an offset.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{amsmath,suetterl,graphicx,mathrsfs}

\newfont{\suet}{suet14}
\newfont{\schwell}{schwell}
%\newfont{\schwellv}{schwell scaled \magstep5}
%\newfont{\suetv}{suet14 scaled \magstep5}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Let \mbox{\usefont{T1}{wesu}{b}{n} E}\hspace{0.5ex} be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
    \item Let \mbox{\usefont{T1}{wesu}{b}{sl} E}\hspace{0.75ex} be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
    \item Let \textsuetterlin{E} be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
    \item Let \mbox{\suet E} be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
    \item Let \scalebox{0.5}{\schwell E}\hspace{0.5ex} be a $\sigma$-algebra. 

    \item Let $\mathcal E$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
    \item Let \reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\pounds}} be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
    \item Let $\mathscr Z$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
    \item Let $\mathscr E$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. 

    \item Let $\mathcal T$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
    \item Let $\mathscr T$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
    \item Let \textsuetterlin{T} be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
    \item Let \mbox{\suet T} be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
    \item Let \scalebox{0.5}{\schwell T}\hspace{0.5ex} be a $\sigma$-algebra. 

%   \item Let \mbox{\schwellv E} be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
%   \item Let \mbox{\suetv E} be a $\sigma$-algebra. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note that the quality of the code is improvable.

It is not harmful to name the context in which the letter appeared as some of us might work on that particular field.

[image]

Comment: This answer earned my a Grace Hopper hat.

Comment: This may be a time where the `enumerate` environment isn't the way to go.  I count 11 `\item`s, but there are nine in the output.

Comment: @CampanIgnis I had the chance to hear ADM Hopper speak ( a seminar at my organization), a number of decades ago.  After all, my organization housed the 1st computer (ENIAC).  She carried around her "nanosecond" with her, a 20 cm string of cable.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I really envy you.

Comment: I knew a number of folks who had programmed the ENIAC early in their career (did you know it was a base-10 computer?).  The other notable who spoke at my university, when I was an undergraduate, was Linus Pauling.  That was interesting, though by that advanced age, he was on his Vitamin C kick.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Amazing. My closest "achievement" of this kind was seeing the Bell Labs from the outside by chance. My schedule did not allow any interaction with them. But they surely would be annoyed, hence I would not try to visit them.

Comment: See https://ftp.arl.army.mil/ftp/historic-computers/png/sac1.png.  The ENIAC was later in the building pictured under construction.  I work in the building behind that one.  Can you see the names of this group??!!  von Neumann, von Karman, Urey, Rabi, Dryden, Lewis... See also https://ftp.arl.army.mil/ftp/historic-computers/png/?C=N;O=D